# querySelector appears to be recognizing "#submit" from input id="submit" and another input type="submit"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I made a function to toggle between two elements' style.display to "none" or "block". 
The problem I get here is that "send" button seems to share the same behaviour of "toggle" button. This is not something I've specified for it to do. I wonder if this has to do with type="submit" being present in the input.

```js
let binary = document.querySelector('#submit')
binary.addEventListener('click', toggler);


function toggler() {
 let phaseTwo = document.querySelector('.phasetwo');
 let phaseOne = document.querySelector('.phaseone');


 if (phaseOne.style.display == "none") {
  phaseTwo.style.display = "none";
  phaseOne.style.display = "block";
 } else {

  phaseTwo.style.display = "block";
  phaseOne.style.display = "none";

 }


}
```

```css
.phaseone {
 display: block;
}
 
.phasetwo {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>html</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div class="phaseone">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="phasetwo">
   <form id="moveConfig"class="config">
    Red: <br>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="5000"> ms <br>
    Yellow: <br>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="3000"> ms <br>
    Green: <br>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="5000"> ms <br>
    <input id="send" type="submit" value="send">
   </form>
  
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="" value="toggle">
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reason for "the same behavior" is the attribute `type="submit"` on the send button.

What it actually does is submitting the form and thus refreshing it.

Ways of fixing:

1. Put the type to `type=button` and handle the button click via JS. Button type won't submit the form by default.
2. Remove the form element (not a best practice) as submit types are usually meant to work with forms.

Here's the updated code snippet:

```js
let binary = document.querySelector('#submit')
binary.addEventListener('click', toggler);


function toggler() {
 let phaseTwo = document.querySelector('.phasetwo');
 let phaseOne = document.querySelector('.phaseone');


 if (phaseOne.style.display == "none") {
  phaseTwo.style.display = "none";
  phaseOne.style.display = "block";
 } else {

  phaseTwo.style.display = "block";
  phaseOne.style.display = "none";

 }


}
```

```css
.phaseone {
 display: block;
}
 
.phasetwo {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>html</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div class="phaseone">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="phasetwo">
   <form id="moveConfig"class="config">
    Red: <br>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="5000"> ms <br>
    Yellow: <br>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="3000"> ms <br>
    Green: <br>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="5000"> ms <br>
    <input id="send" type="button" value="send">
   </form>
  
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="button" name="" value="toggle">
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your fiddle in codepen: codepen.io/vac1911/pen/ZEYYBGm

What's happening is that the #send input is submitting the form, which creates an HTTP request to an invalid destination. jsFiddle handles this by resetting the fiddle, codepen handles this by freaking out.

Comment: I see! So I fixed it by replacing <form> with <div>. Because I'm not going to send anything to a server.  all the processing is done with javascript on clientside.This should be the correct move? Or am i going in the wrong direction. Thanks

Comment: Sounds fine to me.